# iMacros can't write comments in Disqus.com

Tags: html, imacros, disqus

I recently started using iMacros to automate tasks in Disqus.com. After using it to fill in Sign Up forms automatically (Page can be found [here](https://disqus.com/profile/signup/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdisqus.com%2F)) everything seemed fine, the record function recorded exactly what I was inputting and I could play it just fine. For instance I got this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:display-name-input CONTENT=josephbeadles
```

But when I went to an actual disqus blog (If you want to try it yourself [here](https://disqus.com/home/channel/newsviews/discussion/channel-newsviews/why_donald_trump_wont_fold_polls_and_people_speak/) is one) and tried to record me typing something, it recorded nothing. First you have to click "Join the Discussion" and when I typed nothing was recorded. However when I clicked it a second time I got other code which I think is what I want, but it still doesn't record it. I think it might be because the sign up forms are of type INPUT:TEXT while the comment forms are of a different type. when clicking "Join the Discussion" twice I got these 2 things:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Join<SP>the<SP>discussion…
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:
```

As you can see it doesn't record what I write. I then tried recording a reply, and this time it gave me some really long thing:

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Reply
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CONTENTEDITABLE:true&&CLASS:textarea&&TABINDEX:0&&ROLE:textbox&&ARIA-MULTILINE:true&&DATA-ROLE:editable&&ARIA-LABEL:Join<SP>the<SP>discussion…&&TXT:
```

So now I think that it might be because it is of type div. But I have no idea how I can input text into one of these forms, so I came here for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to record your operations in ‘Experimental event recording mode’.

Comment: @Shugar Thanks it worked perfectly! I'll start using this a lot now whenever I can't get things to work, it seems to be really useful.